# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' when module seems to be already installed

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error when I have the module installed. I'm running this on a mac osx catalina 10.15.6

I've also installed this in a virtual environment using these steps:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In addition, I installed `google` to be safe.

```
pip install google
```

Yet it still complains that it can't find google.

Error:

```
    import google.cloud.logging as glog1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Called here:

```
import google.cloud.logging as glog1
```

Doing a pip list:

```
google                   3.0.0
google-api-core          1.22.4
google-auth              1.22.1
google-cloud-core        1.4.3
google-cloud-logging     1.15.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
```

How do I resolve this? I'm sure I have the right module installed. Thanks.

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/), the correct usage of `google-cloud-logging` is via `from google.cloud import logging` or `from google.cloud import logging_v2`. When you use it the correct way, do you still get an error?

Comment: no luck. I tried both - from google.cloud import logging_v2 as glog1 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'  and   from google.cloud import logging as glog1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Comment: i'm running this on a mac catalina 10.15.6 if that helps.

Comment: It seems like `google` is not installed. If you have multiple pythons, it may be installed in one and not the other. If you are using a virtual environment, it may not be installed in that environment.

Comment: i'm using virtualenv (i added those steps to my question). I've recreated it a couple of times and for good measure installed google too.. Its still complaining that it can't find it - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the google installation directory is included in the PYTHONPATH env var.

Comment: That's a good point, but python will have several builtin places that it looks. Most installations won't need a PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `google-api-python-client` in the requirements.txt instead. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) for reference.